# JWT store at server database

Tags: node.js, jwt

Hello I have a query regarding JWT and authentication. In authentication, does the server have to store the JWT as well and have it related to the client?

When the client log in, it receives the JWT token and store it in localStorae with the "auth" key:

For example, this is a client's basic code

```
const user{
  email:user_email,
  password:user_password
  //other field 
}

axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/login", user)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.success === false) {
        //   password or user does not exist!
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem("auth", response.data.token);
          setTimeout(() => {
            history.push("/");
          }, 3000);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
};
```

Then in our Routes, we can check if there is a token and if so, we can access certain urls that are only accessible when logged in:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  return <>{token ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}</>;
};
```

But my question comes from: when the client sends a new request (once logged in) doing a POST, GET, DELETE, does the HTTPS packet data need to be in JSON format with the corresponding token? But if so, the server must have the JWT stored to confirm that the user is registered and is who they say they are. So what is the difference with a session?

How do you check if the server doesn't have the JWT stored in its database that the client is who it claims to be?

For example, in django, must there be a field that is jwt?

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    token = models.BigIntegerField(default=None)
    #Otros campos
```

Answer (score 1):

A jwt typically contains a set of so called claims, one if them oftentimes is the `sub` claim which denotes the `subject` for whom this token was issued. Depending on the particular issuer, this claim may also be named differently. Another typically claim is `exp` which denotes a timestamp, when this token expires.

Furthermore a JWT should be signed by a trusted party (the issuer). This can be your own server or any other trusted party (for instance sign-in with Google or something like that). If you are able to verify that signature, you are safe to assume the token wasn't tampered with.

So if you find a `sub` claim in a token whichs signature you can verify, you can easily identify the user. If you furthermore check the expiration, you can reject tokens which are not valid anymore.

But if you don't store the token at the backend, you won't be able to revoke such a token prematurely and it will be valid until it expires. That may, or may be not, a problem, depending on your usecase.

Comment: So if the same server generates the token, then when the JSON string arrives from the client with the token, does it trust it only or does it have to store it so that when the http packet arrives, it confirms that it is the same token that was previously sent?

Comment: typically, you don't add the token in the payload of a request but in the `Authorization` header. And I really don't understand what you mean with the second question. The token is *signed*, and if the signature checks out, you can trust it. No need for storing it at the server ...

Comment: I understand that the token is the signature, that if an HTTP packet is signed it is reliable but if I invent a token, am I also reliable? If there is a malicious client that signs a packet with a random token? how do you detect that on the server side?

Comment: No, the token is *not the signature*, the token is signed with the private key of the issuer (ie your server or a trusted third party). A client cannot just "*invent*" a token. That won't check out on signature validation ...